# How to get fullDocumentBeforeChange from MongoDB Change Streams in NodeJS with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose and MongoDB and Nodejs and I want to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection and console log the document before change and the update description.

The actual result: I can only log the update description.

```
const didChangeStream = model.collection.watch({
  fullDocument: 'updateLookup',
  fullDocumentBeforeChange: 'whenAvailable'
});
didChangeStreamAlert.on('change', async (event) => {
  const {
    documentKey,
    fullDocument,
    fullDocumentBeforeChange,
    updateDescription
  } = event;
  console.log('fullDocumentBeforeChange', fullDocumentBeforeChange);
  console.log('updateDescription', updateDescription);
});
```

I switch to mongoDB v6.0.3 and I tried to enable the changeStreamPreAndPostImages for myCollection using:

```
db.runCommand ( { collMod: "myCollection", changeStreamPreAndPostImages: { enabled: false } } );
```

> {
> ok: 1,
> '$clusterTime': {
> clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1671719738, i: 1 }),
> signature: {
> hash: Binary(Buffer.from("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "hex"),
> 0),
> keyId: Long("0")
> }
> },
> operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1671719738, i: 1 })
> }

the db.runCommand worked for me but in nodejs the fullDocumentBeforeChange is null.

In mongoDB v5, the fullDocumentBeforeChange is not displayed and
in mongoDB v6 fullDocumentBeforeChange is null.

Comment: Did you enable [`changeStreamPreAndPostImages` field for the collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/update/#document-pre--and-post-images)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Hi, I tried to enable it using db.createCollection() :

`db.createCollection(
   "myCollection",
   { changeStreamPreAndPostImages: { enabled: true } }
);`

I got this error: 

`BSON field 'create.changeStreamPreAndPostImages' is an unknown field.`

and I tired using `db.runCommand ( { collMod: "myCollection", changeStreamPreAndPostImages: { enabled: false } } )`

but I got this error:
`MongoServerError: not authorized on myDatabase to execute command ...`

Comment: What is the MongoDB server version?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I was using MongoDB  v5 and switched to v6  the `db.runCommand`  worked for me but in nodejs the fullDocumentBeforeChange is null.

the goodthing it's showing the fullDocumentBeforeChange. but the problem why it's null ?

Comment: Please edit your question and show all the command attempts, etc.

Comment: Is  `enabled: false` a typo in the question? it should be `true`

Comment: sorry, It's was my bad I switched to true and It worked. ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched to MongoDB 6.0.3 and I run the command:

```
db.runCommand ( { collMod: "myCollection", changeStreamPreAndPostImages: { enabled: true } } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for hours and this is my solution:

1. Install mongosh run:
   `db.runCommand ({ collMod: "myCollection", changeStreamPreAndPostImages: { enabled: true }});`
2. Also run: `db.runCommand({ collMod: "myCollection", recordPreImages: true })`
3. Then make sure you have the latest version of mongoose installed (This was the issue in my case).
4. Make sure your MongoDB version is >= 6.0
5. Also refer [this](https://dev.to/greggcbs/mongodb-how-to-get-fulldocument-from-changestream-when-a-document-is-deleted-2b3j) to properly setup your change_stream

Answer (score 1):

You can enable `changeStreamPreAndPostImages` in the mongoose Schema via `collectionOptions`

```
new Schema({}, { collectionOptions: { changeStreamPreAndPostImages: { enabled: true } } })
```

Note that this creates the collection with changeStreamPreAndPostImages enabled, but it does not update an existing collection.

Alternatively, you can use the mongo `createCollection` or `collMod` commands to enable `changeStreamPreAndPostImages` outside of mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `changeStreamPreAndPostImages: { enabled: true }` to your Schema.

```js
const addressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    city: String,
    street: String,
},
  {
  changeStreamPreAndPostImages: { enabled: true }
}
);
```

For more detail on how to implement at MongoDb Altas, see [how to set the db.createCollection() parameter in Mongodb Altas or Mongoose](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-set-the-db-createcollection-parameter-in-mongodb-altas-or-mongoose/250879).